# call an instance of a previous class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am programming a `Spreadsheet` in java. Therefore I am using `Swing`, `Jtable`. It is working pretty good, but there is something I can't get figured out.

This is how it is working right now:

I have a Main class, this one creates a Sheet, `Sheetholder` etc.

> When a user inserts a value into a cell, the value is checked whether it points to another cell (e.g. '=B17') or whether it contains a formula ('=5*5'). Since I need the possibily of recursion (e.g. '=5*B17') the value is send to a class, called Parameter.

The problem is that this class needs to access the Sheet: e.g. `'Sheet.getContent(1,16)'`. How can I achieve this?

I have tried multiple options, but since the Main is a constructor I can't simply call the `Main.sheet.`

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why can't you just pass the sheet into the method that does the evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Sheet property to your Cells, containing the Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The Parameter class needs to be able to take a reference to the Sheet object that contains the cell from the formula.